Partial Derivative Question About Gas' Internal Energy
I am working on Thomas' Calculus (also here). I found a question that I am unable to solve.

Let ${U = f(P,V,T)}$ be the internal energy of a gas that obeys the ideal gas law ${PV = nRT}$ ($n$ and $R$ constant). Find ${\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial P} \right)_{V}}$.

I used a method in the textbook and $(P, V)$ be the independent variables, $(x,y,z)$ be the intermediate variables where ${P = x}$, ${V = y}$, and ${T = z}$, and $U$ be the dependent variable. However, I cannot isolate ${U}$ and, therefore, cannot apply the method.
Without knowledge of Chemistry or Physics, is it possible to find the partial derivative using only the given information? Any help is appreciated!

Do we know anything about $f$ at all?

Unfortunately, no. The question doesn't say anything about the behavior of ${f}$.

From my side, the solution looks like this:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\right)_V=
\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\frac{\partial P}{\partial P}+
\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}+
\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}
$$
$$
=\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}(1)+
\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}(0)+
\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\left(\frac{V}{nR}\right)
$$
$$
=\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\left(\frac{V}{nR}\right)
$$
Similarly, you can also find the case for constant volume:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V=
\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}+
\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}+
\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\frac{\partial T}{\partial T}
$$
$$
=\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\left(\frac{nR}{V}\right)+
\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}(0)+
\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}(1)
$$
$$
=\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\left(\frac{nR}{V}\right)+\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}
$$

The  state equation of an ideal gas $$p\ V = n \ R\ T$$ and the inner energy by kinetic energy only $$U = n\  R \ T,$$ so f is independent on the first two variables and effectively the experiment acts by $$ U = p \ V$$.
U is a very bad state function to use as it does not count the mechanical energy of compression at constant temperature, an experiment only possible in contact with a thermal bath.
For the ideal gas the potential U is only good for a thermical isolated systems and establishing the distribution function.
Experimentally with $V=\text{const}$,  $ p\to p+ dp$  can  be increased  by   $R \ dT$ only. with V as the constant of proportionality.
Key words: Maxwell relations, Borns thermodynamic square, caloric and state equations. Maxwell velocity distribution, Boltzmann energy distributions.
Formal algebra often is misleading without reference to the fact, that experiments are curves along states of thermal equlibrium in a state space on hypersurfaces on the one hand and that these experiments are modeled by distributions with extremal values of their entropy S in  $$dU = T dS + p dV$$ that is
$$S = \text{Ex}_\rho{ \log \rho}$$
in a statistical model with distribtion $\rho(x,p)$ in the space of position and momenenta of classical point particles.
For a real gas replace
$$df(p ,\ V, \ T)\ = \ \partial_1 f \ dp + \partial_2 dV \ + \  \partial_3 \ dT $$
with
$$0= dV = \frac{1}{p}\ n \  R \  dT - \frac{1}{p^2} \  n \  R \  T \ dp   \quad \rightarrow p \ dT \ =  \ T \  dp  $$
If such a equation makes sense it easy to test: Check wikipedia if
$$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial p}\right)_V$$ appears somewhere on pages of Maxwell relations. The fact that $p,V$ are conjugate variables in Borns square as $S,T$ etc is suspicious like in Hamiltonian free mechanics in an Intervall $L$ with
$$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}, \quad \left(\partial_{\frac{1}{L}} \ \frac{p^2}{2m}\right))_{L=\text{const}} $$.
